# web2py: not showing every field with SQLFORM.grid()

Tags: web2py

How am I supposed to show just a subset of fields from a table with SQLFORM.grid()?

I have tried reading both the web2py manual and DAL reference (which is very, very lacking) but can't figure this out. Basic problem I have is that any procedure I can figure out to remove fields from the set return a set of rows, which I can't seem to cast back to a set. SQLFORM.grid(), however, requires a set as input. It's easy to select every field with

```
query = db.t_mytable
return dict(grid=SQLFORM.grid(query))
```

in the controller but how could I show only f_name from t_mytable in the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#SQLFORM.grid-and-SQLFORM.smartgrid):

> `fields` is a list of fields to be fetched from the database. It is
>   also used to determine which fields to be shown in the grid view.

You can also set the "readable" attribute of fields you don't want to display to False:

```
db.mytable.myfield.readable = False
```

Comment: Thank you! The readable attribute did the trick this time. I only read the part about DAL because I didn't realise SQLFORM is described elsewhere.